# Spring boot Data JPA task :test Failed

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, spring-data-jpa

I'm starting to use Data JPA from Spring to interact with Postgres Database, but when I try to build the project, the building phase raise an exception in the applicationTest.

This is my **build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'eu.universome.radio'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

If I comment the dependencies:
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'` the build will be successful.

This is my empty **applicationTest**:

```
package eu.universome.radio.RadioUVMServer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class RadioUvmServerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Here there is the Console Error:

```
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 7.1.1
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: build

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test FAILED

RadioUvmServerApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at Assert.java:97

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

Here you can find the report:
[1]: https://www.universome.eu/wp-content/uploads/RadioUVM/progetto-radio-unime/reports/tests/test/classes/eu.universome.radio.RadioUVMServer.RadioUvmServerApplicationTests.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not sure if you have the dependency added.

`implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.23'`

2. You can check if the driver is on classpath:

```
try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // recheck dependencies
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Amey I solve the problem adding this line
`runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'` to the dependencies section of the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding the line

`runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'`

on **build.gradle** file in section *dependencies*

```
dependencies {
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```